# Convert specific objects to dictionaries before serialization

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using `Json.NET` to serialize validation data for data field. On the .NET side, validation data is a list of `ValidationAttribute` objects. However, I'd like to serialize them in a special form like this:

```
[
  { Type: 'Required', ErrorMessage: '{FieldName} is required' },
  { Type: 'RegularExpression', Pattern: '^\d+$', ErrorMessage: '...'
]
```

In an ideal solution I could simply intercept the object before serialization and, I could create a corresponding `Dictionary<string, object>` object to serialize instead of the original one.

Are there any solutions for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own `JsonConverter` class and convert your collection as you wish.

You just need to create you class and inherit it from `JsonConverter`

```
public class YourSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(YourClassName).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

and then you need to decorate your class which will be serialized with the attribute (looks like it's not what you want)

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(YourSerializer))]
public class YourClassName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

or, pass an instance of your serializer to Serialize methos:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sourceObj, Formatting.Indented, new YourSerializer(typeof(yourClassName)));
```

Here is a few links:

- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm
- http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Actually I was aware of JsonConverters at some level, but didn't think that this task can be easily solved with them. I used a custom JsonConverter and filled a JObject according my needs. Thank you.